# Package com.google does not exist

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans IDE 7.0.1.
I base my question on the CalculatorApp sample application available with the IDE.
The sample is running fine but I wish I could use some JSON, ad so I download google-gson-stream-1.7.1.jar library, and included it in my libraries :
- right click on "Library", then "Properties" then "Add JAR/Folder" and selected my JAR (located somewhere in "My Documents/Download".

The problem is that when i type the following :

```
import com.google.gson;
```

(or even com.google), the IDE fires a "Package com.google does not exist". The JAR and its hierarchy is correctly shown on the left side pane,in the "Libraries" section. Most surprising, the IDE can autocomplete the com.google.****** stuff.

AFAIK, I need to further to get this work, don't I ? Any ideas ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java, import statements are for classes and interfaces (types) not for packages themselves. Are you sure you tried to import a class under `com.google.gson` package and not the package itself?

`import com.google.gson.Foo;` should work.

So should

`import com.google.gson.*;` or
`import com.google.*;`

Note however that wildcard imports aren't particularly recommended.

Comment: Indeed ! import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter and import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader did the trick. I wasn't aware of that, many thanks !

Comment: I have the same error , did the same thing including library , yet it still throws that error

Answer (score -1):

I am using:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
```